# Attempting to customize keyboard shortcuts results in reproducible crash

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, workspace

I have a keyboard with no super key, but would like to move between workspaces. The following steps results in a crash.

(1) System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Workspaces
(2) Press any setting (like "Switch to workspace 1")
(3) Notice settings menu freezes. No applications can be pressed, even though mouse continues to be controllable. 
(4) Pressing the powerbutton on the machine seems to restore settings back to normal, however the setting changes to disabled.

Screenshot of what seems like relevant portions of the System Logs based on timing and reported failures:

[image]

Screenshot: [image: Systems Settings screen showing disabled settings]

Thoughts on how to resolve? Thanks!

Comment: Very thorough description! I can't help you myself, but this sounds like it would make a very complete bug report. I suppose https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-keyboard would be the right place to post it.

Comment: Sure thing, will add tonight.